# global static variable not changeable within a function? (gcc-89, uclinux)

Tags: c, static

I hope this is no duplicate but I had no idea what to search for. I have a strange behavieour with a c program and a static variable. 
About the program: I am configuring a serial port and change the serial file descriptor in a configure_tty(int *fd_ptr) function.The program is an application for an embedded linux running microblaze uclinux. I am programming and cross compiling under Ubuntu 14.

I stripped it down to the following example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int fd;
static void config_tty(int *fd_ptr);

static void config_tty(int *fd_ptr){
    int desc = 5;   // here was open(serial port)
    *fd_ptr = desc;
}

void main(){
    printf("before: %i\n", fd);
    config_tty(&fd);
    printf("after: %i\n", fd);
}
```

This gives me `before: 0` and then `after: 5` what is what I expected.

*I have to mention that my original program is cross-compiled with `gcc -89` parameter and the compiler for microblaze uclinux.* 
I found the problem thanks to gdbserver and gdb over TCP.

Within the config_tty everything is fine but right after `*fd_ptr = desc;` fd didn't change.

So I tried different things and now comes my question:

Changing `static int fd;` to `int fd;` fixed it. 
Can anyone tell me what is the reason for this and why it is no problem in my example on Codelite for Windows? Is it compiler-specific?

Comment: Since your example works but code you don't show does not I can only guess. In the code that does not work are you using more than one source file? If so I would check to make sure that you don't have more than one static with the same name (each translation unit gets its own copy of variables declared static).

Comment: This might be the result of an optimization. At least in the reduced example, the compiler can inline `config_tty` and replace the use of `fd` with a simple register, avoiding memory access. Since `fd` is static, it knows no-one will access it from the outside, and can prove the optimization isn't externally visible. When you omit the static, another translation unit can access `fd`, hence the compiler must not bypass its modification. Have no idea if this also applies to your original code, of course.

Comment: have you tried compiling with `static volatile int fd;` ? (or the equivalent)

Comment: @SoronelHaetir The code consists only of one file and there is no second declaration of this variable

Comment: @AhmedMasud This will give me a compiler error `invalid conversion from ‘volatile int*’ to ‘int*’` at the line where I call the function in main (line 13 in above example)

Comment: @eran I am not very familiar with compiler optimizations. Do you mean that the compiler will replace the call of config_tty in main()? Does your explanation apply if I have only one source file?

Comment: Although we appreciate your attempt to simplify the problem for presentation here, an example that does not reproduce the problem is of little use to us.  It does not give us a basis on which we can actually answer the question.  Please, therefore, present a *bona fide* [mcve].  But if I had to guess without seeing the code, then I would second @SoronelHaetir.  I would furthermore note that one way people sometime end up with multiple `static` variables with the same name is by declaring such a variable in a header file.  But that's speculative.

Comment: Maybe you have a local declaration of `fd` in your function that shadows the global

Comment: @Stefatronik One of the first thing a compiler tries to do is substitute memory accesses with registers - it's much faster. If you tell the compiler `fd` is "private" for this translation unit by making it static, and the compiler can generate code that will produce the same output using register instead of globals, it will. If you omit the `static` then some other translation unit can access `fd`, hence the compiler must use the global. Same goes to declaring it `volatile` (which means someone outside of the program might read or modify it).

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks for your thoughts. You are right I'll put the example on the target hardware tomorrow and see what happens there. 
I verified my code. It consists of only one source file and a search brought only one declaration for this variable. By the way I debugged it with gdb and could exactly reproduce at which line the value gets lost - like described the problem lies between return and the next code line.